# Caveats to using InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE for numeric input

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an input field where I would like the user to enter a number (alphabet is `[0-9]`). Generally the IME that appears when specifying the field as `TYPE_CLASS_PHONE` is much nicer for numeric input than `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` (**at least on my Samsung dev device**). However I get the feeling that there is some caveat to using `TYPE_CLASS_PHONE`... why would both types exist if `TYPE_CLASS_PHONE` is strictly better?

Is there a good reason not to use `TYPE_CLASS_PHONE` for numeric input that is not a phone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TYPE_CLASS_PHONE` is specifically for phone numbers and supports no variations or flags.

`TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` supports the following flags: `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED` and `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL`. It also supports the following variations: `TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL` and `TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD`.

Also:

`TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`:

[image: Number]

`TYPE_CLASS_PHONE`:

[image: Phone]

Comment: Hmm, I see, this looks quite different on my Samsung device (as I suspected). The numeric input looks quite stupid (it displays the normal keyboard with everything but the digits disabled).